# Why I'm getting only the last row filled with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I will explain a bit what the programm does: It just get a JSON file with a psychology or other kind test and make a correction. You can create a test with different areas or subsets with their own correction and porcentages respect the total. Later on, it asks the user if they want to save the data in a xsls file for further analysis.

I'm trying to fill and excel with some user information. Thing is, I only get the last answer and score of every subset. It seems like the rows are getting overwritten or something.

Some code:

This is the method which is called:

```java
   public void subsetWriter(String userName, RandomTest t, Corrector c) {
        Workbook subsetWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = subsetWorkbook.createSheet(userName);

        styleCreation(sheet);

        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        Row titleRow = sheet.createRow(1);
        for (int i = 2; i < t.getQuestions().size() + 2; i++) {
            punctuations = sheet.createRow(i);
        }

        Cell subsetHeader;
        Cell scoreTitle;
        Cell answerTitle;

        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 1, 2));
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 3, 4));
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 5, 6));

        int plusTwoCounter = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < c.getSubsetNames().size(); i++) {
            subsetHeader = headerRow.createCell(plusTwoCounter + 2);
            subsetHeader.setCellValue(c.getSubsetNames().get(i));
            subsetHeader.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

            scoreTitle = titleRow.createCell(plusTwoCounter + 2);
            scoreTitle.setCellValue(COLUMN1);
            scoreTitle.setCellStyle(titleStyle);

            answerTitle = titleRow.createCell(plusTwoCounter + 3);
            answerTitle.setCellValue(COLUMN2);
            answerTitle.setCellStyle(titleStyle);

            fillSubset(i, t.getSubsets().get(c.getSubsetNames().get(i)), t.getSubsets().get(c.getSubsetNames().get(i)), punctuations);

            plusTwoCounter += 2;
        }

        rowResization(sheet, 1, 7);
        saveFile(subsetWorkbook, userName);
    }
```

A helper static method to fill the subsets:

```java
        private static void fillSubset(int subsetPosition, ArrayList<Question> scores, ArrayList<Question> answers, Row punctuations) {
        Integer[] scorePositions = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        Integer[] answerPositions = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

        Cell scoreCell;
        Cell answerCell;

        for (int j = 0; j < scores.size(); j++) {
            scoreCell = punctuations.createCell(scorePositions[subsetPosition]);
            scoreCell.setCellValue(scores.get(j).getScore());

            answerCell = punctuations.createCell(answerPositions[subsetPosition]);
            answerCell.setCellValue(answers.get(j).getUserAnswer());
        }
    }
```

Score and Answer are class attributes of Question, those lists of Question objects comes from a HashMap which holds the subsets name and their correspondent list of questions.

I hope I made myself clear, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: In your call `fillSubset(i, t.getSubsets().get(c.getSubsetNames().get(i)), t.getSubsets().get(c.getSubsetNames().get(i)), punctuations);` the `Row punctuations` alsways is the same row. It always is the last one created in your loop `for (int i = 2; i < t.getQuestions().size() + 2; i++) { punctuations = sheet.createRow(i); }`. Or why do you think it would be different?

Comment: Oh, I misread the documentation or something may inclined me to think that when using the loop where I create the punctuation row I'm creating 9 rows (```t.getQuestions().size() + 2```) that can be filled later on. I thought that worked that way. I will correct it, thanks a lot!

Comment: It seem I just can't fill multiple rows vertically. Whenever I create a new row it overwrittes all the cells.

Comment: Do creating each row only **once** using [Sheet.createRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createRow-int-). If needed again, get the row using [Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-). If you don not know whether a row is created already, do using: `Sheet sheet = ...; ... int rowNumber = ...; ... Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber); if (row==null) row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber); ...`. So: Try get the row. If that returns `null`, then the row needs to be created.

Comment: ```for (int j = 0; j < scores.size(); j++) {
            if (sheet.getRow(j + 2) == null) {
                punctuations = sheet.createRow(j + 2);
            }
            scoreCell = punctuations.createCell(scorePositions[subsetPosition]);
            scoreCell.setCellValue(scores.get(j).getScore());

            answerCell = punctuations.createCell(answerPositions[subsetPosition]);
            answerCell.setCellValue(answers.get(j).getUserAnswer());
        }``` I'm trying as you suggested but it gave me this: https://imgur.com/JUeErV9, logic seems fine now, idk what's happening

Comment: That is not was I suggested. Try `for (int j = 0; j < scores.size(); j++) { punctuations = sheet.getRow(j + 2); if (punctuations == null) punctuations = sheet.createRow(j + 2); scoreCell = ... }`

Comment: Output now: https://ibb.co/4WD8Bkn , this doesn't make sense.